# How to access ref from a non-related component?

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I have a fixed-positioned navigation bar that I want to make static when some menu down in the app expands.
The problem is that both components are far away from each other in the app hirarchy.

```js
const Nav = () => {
  const navRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <nav
      ref={navRef}
    ></nav>
  );
}

const Menu = () => {
  // I want to access the nav ref here to change its style when the menu expands
  return (
    <ul></ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this ...

```
const App = () => {
  const navRef = useRef();

  const setStyleForNav = (style) => {
    navRef.current.style = style;  
  };

  return (
    <Nav ref={navRef}/>
    <Menu setStyleForNav={setStyleForNav}/>
  )
};

const Nav = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <nav
      ref={ref}
    ></nav>
  );
});

const Menu = ({setStyleForNav}) => {
  // I want to access the nav ref here to change its style when the menu expands
  return (
    <ul></ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank u for ur response. The problem is that the two components are too far away in the app architecture. Going this way will involve tons of passing, which i don't think is a clean way.

Comment: Then your problem is not ref, it is just prop drilling. There are 2 main solutions to this - useContext() and composition pattern.